# Primefaces modal not updating

Tags: jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog

Hi I've been stuck for sometime getting a modal form to update, it's loading the data, and it's calling the function - it's just not passing the data back to the server

```
    <h:form id="modal">
    <p:dialog  widgetVar="modalText"  styleClass="modalSceneText" modal="true" dynamic="true" >

        <p:panel id="sceneText">

            <p:inputTextarea id="sceneName" immediate="true"  style="width: 200px" rows="1" counter="labelCount" maxlength="20" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." value="#{CustomerDashboardController.selectedScene.title}"/><h:outputText id="labelCount" /><br/>
            <p:inputTextarea id="sceneDescription" immediate="true"  rows="10" cols="50" value="#{CustomerDashboardController.selectedScene.description}" counter="descriptionCount" maxlength="1000" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" /><br/>
            <h:outputText id="descriptionCount" />

        </p:panel>

        <p:ajax event="close" process="@form" immediate="true" update=":form:locationScenes" listener="#{CustomerDashboardController.saveSelectedScene()}" />

    </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

I've tried it inside and outside the form, I've tried everything I can think off..

The sceneName & sceneDescription are loading the correct data, they're just not saving any changes when the modal/dialog is closed. `saveSelectedScene()` is being called fine.

EDIT

I can get it to save with a

```
<p:commandLink value="save" action="#{CustomerDashboardController.saveSelectedScene()}"/>
```

Which isn't very pretty. Seems the problem is trying to save on the close event.

Comment: What is the scope of the CustomerDashboardController? And are you sure that you don't have nested forms?

Comment: Thanks. Yea I don't have nested forms. I've tried one form, or 2 forms.

I can get it to save with a  <p:commandLink value="save" action="#{CustomerDashboardController.saveSelectedScene()}"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that the saveSelectedScene() method which is called from the listener in the ajax component is using the old values of the inputTextarea's.

As a workaround you can use a remoteCommand component and call that on your close event instead:

```
<h:form id="modal">
    <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update=":form:locationScenes" actionListener="#{CustomerDashboardController.saveSelectedScene()}" />
    <p:dialog  widgetVar="modalText"  styleClass="modalSceneText" modal="true" dynamic="true" >

        <p:panel id="sceneText">

            <p:inputTextarea id="sceneName" immediate="true"  style="width: 200px" rows="1" counter="labelCount" maxlength="20" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." value="#{CustomerDashboardController.selectedScene.title}"/><h:outputText id="labelCount" /><br/>
            <p:inputTextarea id="sceneDescription" immediate="true"  rows="10" cols="50" value="#{CustomerDashboardController.selectedScene.description}" counter="descriptionCount" maxlength="1000" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" /><br/>
            <h:outputText id="descriptionCount" />

        </p:panel>

        <p:ajax event="close" process="@form" immediate="true"   oncomplete="rc()" />

    </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

Also consider if the immediate="true" are really necessary in your code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing immediate="true" from both input elements and p:ajax tag? It seems to me that you don't need it - especially not on p:ajax tag.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yea I've tried that. Doesn't help. It's so hard to debug this stuff.